# How do users / members have to be notified of a change in terms and conditions?

Tags: terms-of-service, education

However, I'm wondering what sort of due process a company has to go through before they assume that I've read an email regarding a change to their terms and conditions. it. For example, a bank will send letters and multiple emails. Most websites send a single email (which you cannot opt out of). Some will send an email which you can unsubscribe from.

For context, my University sent a "Welcome back" to the new term email, from a mailing address which you can unsubscribe from. About halfway down the email was the statement "We've made some updates to our student Code of Discipline and have added a policy on sexual misconduct".

Aside from the (questionable) contents of this new policy, has my University does everything required of it for me to be aware of this new policy? If anecdotal experience matters, I've told around 30 people that this new policy is in place - nobody I've told had even read the email.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, your contract with the company will specify the manner by which the terms and conditions can be modified, and normally they will specify that sending an email to the last known email address of a person is sufficient notice.

This is not generally modified by any specific statutory or regulatory requirement, but it is possible that some country or political subdivision does have such a requirement and this can't be answered definitively without specifying a jurisdiction that governs the relationship.

In the case of a public educational institution, notice is often provided as a courtesy only and the institution has the legal authority to change its policies without notice at any time, and you are bound to them whether or not you receive notice, so long as it is possible to determine the institution's policies by requesting them affirmatively.